# Error in replace function jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

while coding i came across this piece of code . When i execute it , shows error that "encrypt.encrypt(...).replace is not a function". it would be of great help if anybody can tell me my mistake. Thanks in advance.

```
 $(function() {
        $("#query").click(function(){
            let password = randomString(20);
            const optionsObj = {
                url: $("#url").val(),
                password: password
            };     
            const options = JSON.stringify(optionsObj);
            const encryptedEncodedOptions = encrypt.encrypt(options).replace(/\//g, "_").replace(/\+/g, "-");
            const url = urlPrefix + encryptedEncodedOptions;
```

Comment: What is `encrypt`?

Comment: Have you made custom function `encrypt`?

Comment: this part `encrypt.encrypt(options)` must return a `string` .. check what is happening now

Comment: const encrypt = new JSEncrypt();
yes , encrypt is a custom object .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `encrypt` class which is not a part of out-of-the-box vanilla Javascript, hence the `encrypt.encrypt.. is not a function` error message. Javascript doesn't know what is `encrypt` unless you define it. If, as you mentioned in your question, you copied this code from somewhere, you must have missed other code defining the `encrypt` class / object.

In case you are trying to use [JSEncrypt library](https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt), make sure you have downloaded the library's JS files and included them in your HTML's header `<script src='...'>` section.

Comment: const encrypt = new JSEncrypt();
i have declared encrypt as an object .

Comment: Have you loaded the library that implements the `JSEncrypt` ?